# How do I dynamically find a disk with free space to create a separate partition using bash

Tags: bash, rhel, partition

I would like to first state that I am new to disk partitioning, so if at any point my desired result is an impossible action to be performed on the workstation, kindly enlighten me on the proper way to achieve a similar outcome. Thanks!

### Question

I would like to write a bash script to manage multiple RHEL workstations, all which may have different number of disks as well as varying disk partitioning.

What I would like to accomplish is to create a new (separate) partition of size `4GiB` on a suitable disk that is found on the workstation, and if the script cannot find anywhere suitable to create a separate partition (due to the disk storage having insufficient unallocated space) the script will then print `"Unable to create separate partition on disk: Insufficient space"` and exit.

Also, when doing this operation, do I have to be concerned about disrupting the `/dev/mapper` Logical Volumes?

### Examples

The example workstation partitions stated here is not an exhaustive list; it's just 2 out of the many configurations that I have in the network of RHEL workstations.

```
Example 1:

# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Disk model: 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device         Start       End   Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1230847   1228800    600M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1230848   3327999   2097152      1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    3328000 134215679 130887680   62.4G Linux LVM
```

In this workstation with only 1 physical disk, I would like the script to automatically find the device that can carve out a separate partition of `4GiB`. For example, if `/dev/sda3` could partition out `4GiB` of space, I would like the final partitioning to be something like this:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Disk model: 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device         Start         End   Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     1230847   1228800    600M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1230848     3327999   2097152      1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    3328000   125827071 122499072   58.4G Linux LVM
/dev/sda4    125827072 134215679   8388608      4G Linux   # numbers here estimated based on calculation only
```

---

```
Example 2:

# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Disk model: 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device         Start       End   Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1230847   1228800    600M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1230848   3327999   2097152      1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    3328000 134215679 130887680   62.4G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Disk model: 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device        Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048 20973567 20971520  10G Linux LVM
/dev/sdb2  20973568 67108830 46135263  22G Linux LVM
```

In this case, assuming `/dev/sda` is full, the script would automatically detect it and partition `/dev/sdb` instead:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Disk model: 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device         Start       End   Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1230847   1228800    600M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1230848   3327999   2097152      1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    3328000 134215679 130887680   62.4G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Disk model: 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device        Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048 20973567 20971520  10G Linux LVM
/dev/sdb2  20973568 58722303 37748736  18G Linux LVM
/dev/sdb3  58722304 67106815  8384512   4G Linux LVM
```

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be a separate partition, or could it be a logical volume? If you don’t know the answer to that, what will the partition be used for?

Comment: @StephenKitt I will be mounting `/var` onto it, as part of benchmark compliance

Comment: Does your benchmark compliance require that `/var` be a separate partition? It would be much easier if it could be a separate logical volume. Incidentally, do you know why example 2 has `/dev/sdb` set up with two LVM partitions? Usually such a setup would have a single partition occupying all the disk, as a physical volume for LVM.

Comment: This is doable (I've done something very close to it), but fdisk isn't the tool to use within a bash script.  `findmnt` and `lsblk` have formatted output that's far easier to parse with a script.  I'll have to dig up the scripts I wrote a few years ago before I can write up an answer.  Meanwhile someone else may have an answer for you sooner.

Comment: @StephenKitt yeah, the benchmark in question is the CIS benchmark for RHEL9, ensuring a separate partition exists for mounting `/var`.. i guess if the max size of a logical volume can't be "breached" and is secure from a cybersecurity perspective, it doesn't matter whether its a partition or a logical volume... not sure why `/dev/sdb` has 2 LVMs, gotta go check it out, may be another rabbit hole i find myself going down if the previous sys admin didnt know what he was doing :p

Comment: @SottoVoce thanks for your help, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use a partition at all, if you have LVM already? You find a volumegroup with enough free space, create a logical volume, put a filesystem on it an mount it at /var.

Comment: @user3188140 what happens if the system does not have a LVM? how can I appropriately repartition the disk to create a 4GiB partition to mount `/var` on? what if the LVM has lesser than 4GiB of space left to allocate to a LV? I need to have a comprehensive (and failproof) script to achieve what i want to in my question, without human intervention in the middle of script execution.